# Syntax error: value, object or array expected

Tags: amp-html, alexa-skills-kit, google-amp

I have a problem with my amp pages and Google not indexing them. Below is a picture of the error.

[image]

Comment: You should always include both the code and the error in text format. Otherwise other people won't find it with search at all.

Comment: Or be able to read it in a reasonable way across devices. Use text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

You are including JavaScript in your page. This is not allowed in AMP.

Specifically, the syntax error you're seeing is complaining that the data you have in `<script type="application/ld+json">...</script>` is not valid JSON. The reason is that you have included JavaScript instead of JSON, so this will not work.